# Resetting password email is not being sent with gmail and Django registration

Tags: django, email, passwords, gmail

I'm trying to send a resetting password email with gmail. The resetting functions below work and redirect to the "success" page after filling in a valid email adress and submitting it for sending, but there is no mail sent. All registration templates are stored in the same dir; myapp/registration.

in settings

```
import smtplib
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587 #465
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'yourpassword'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'youremail@gmail.com'
#EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX = 'something'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

in urls

```
   url(r'^password/change/$',
                    auth_views.password_change,
                    {'post_change_redirect': reverse_lazy('auth_password_change_done')},
                    name='password_change'),
   url(r'^password/change/done/$',
                    auth_views.password_change_done,
                    name='password_change_done'),
   url(r'^password/reset/$',
                    auth_views.password_reset,
                    {'post_reset_redirect': reverse_lazy('auth_password_reset_done')},
                    name='password_reset'),
   url(r'^password/reset/done/$',
                    auth_views.password_reset_done,
                    name='password_reset_done'),
   url(r'^password/reset/complete/$',
                    auth_views.password_reset_complete,
                    name='password_reset_complete'),
   url(r'^password/reset/confirm/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>.+)/$',
                    auth_views.password_reset_confirm,
                    {'post_reset_redirect': reverse_lazy('auth_password_reset_complete')},
                    name='password_reset_confirm'),

      #and now add the registration urls
   url(r'', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
```

in views

```
def password_reset(request, is_admin_site=False,
                   template_name='registration/password_reset_form.html',
email_template_name='registration/password_reset_email.html',
                   subject_template_name='registration/password_reset_subject.txt',
                   password_reset_form=PasswordResetForm,
                   token_generator=default_token_generator,
                   post_reset_redirect=None,
                   from_email=None,
                   current_app=None,
                   extra_context=None,
                   html_email_template_name=None):
    if post_reset_redirect is None:
        post_reset_redirect = reverse('password_reset_done')
    else:
        post_reset_redirect = resolve_url(post_reset_redirect)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = password_reset_form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            opts = {
                'use_https': request.is_secure(),
                'token_generator': token_generator,
                'from_email': from_email,
                'email_template_name': email_template_name,
                'subject_template_name': subject_template_name,
                'request': request,
                'html_email_template_name': html_email_template_name,
            }
            if is_admin_site:
                opts = dict(opts, domain_override=request.get_host())
            form.save(**opts)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(post_reset_redirect)
    else:
        form = password_reset_form()
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'title': _('Password reset'),
    }
    if extra_context is not None:
        context.update(extra_context)
    return TemplateResponse(request, template_name, context,
                            current_app=current_app)


def password_reset_done(request,
                        template_name='registration/password_reset_done.html',
                        current_app=None, extra_context=None):
    context = {
        'title': _('Password reset successful'),
    }
    if extra_context is not None:
        context.update(extra_context)
    return TemplateResponse(request, template_name, context,
                            current_app=current_app)



@sensitive_post_parameters()
@never_cache
def password_reset_confirm(request, uidb64=None, token=None,

template_name='registration/password_reset_confirm.html',
                           token_generator=default_token_generator,
                           set_password_form=SetPasswordForm,
                           post_reset_redirect=None,
                           current_app=None, extra_context=None):
    """
    View that checks the hash in a password reset link and presents a
    form for entering a new password.
    """
    UserModel = get_user_model()
    assert uidb64 is not None and token is not None  # checked by URLconf
    if post_reset_redirect is None:
        post_reset_redirect = reverse('password_reset_complete')
    else:
        post_reset_redirect = resolve_url(post_reset_redirect)


    try:
        uid = urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64)
        user = UserModel._default_manager.get(pk=uid)
    except (TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, UserModel.DoesNotExist):
        user = None

    if user is not None and token_generator.check_token(user, token):
        validlink = True
        title = _('Enter new password')
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = set_password_form(user, request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect(post_reset_redirect)
        else:
            form = set_password_form(user)
    else:
        validlink = False
        form = None
        title = _('Password reset unsuccessful')
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'title': title,
        'validlink': validlink,
        }

    if extra_context is not None:
        context.update(extra_context)

    return TemplateResponse(request, template_name, context,
                            current_app=current_app)

def password_reset_complete(request,
template_name='registration/password_reset_complete.html',
                         current_app=None, extra_context=None):
    context = {
        'login_url': resolve_url(settings.LOGIN_URL),
        'title': _('Password reset complete'),
    }
    if extra_context is not None:
        context.update(extra_context)
    return TemplateResponse(request, template_name, context,
                            current_app=current_app)


def password_change(request,
                    template_name='registration/password_change_form.html',
                    post_change_redirect=None,
                    password_change_form=PasswordChangeForm,
                    current_app=None, extra_context=None):
    if post_change_redirect is None:
        post_change_redirect = reverse('password_change_done')
    else:
        post_change_redirect = resolve_url(post_change_redirect)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = password_change_form(user=request.user, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
           # Updating the password logs out all other sessions for the user
            # except the current one if
            # django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware
            # is enabled.
            update_session_auth_hash(request, form.user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(post_change_redirect)
    else:
        form = password_change_form(user=request.user)
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'title': _('Password change'),
    }
    if extra_context is not None:
        context.update(extra_context)
    return TemplateResponse(request, template_name, context,
                            current_app=current_app)
@login_required
def password_change_done(request,

template_name='registration/password_change_done.html',
                     current_app=None, extra_context=None):
    context = {
        'title': _('Password change successful'),
    }
    if extra_context is not None:
        context.update(extra_context)
    return TemplateResponse(request, template_name, context,
                            current_app=current_app)
```

UPDATE

my email is now sent to gmail but gmail delivers the following errormessage;

```
Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:

     to_email_address@gmail.com

Technical details of permanent failure:
Google tried to deliver your message, but it was rejected by the server for the recipient domain gmail.com by gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com. [2a00:1450:4010:c04::1b].

The error that the other server returned was:
550-5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does not exist. Please try
550-5.1.1 double-checking the recipient's email address for typos or
550-5.1.1 unnecessary spaces. Learn more at
550 5.1.1 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=6596 ok4si3174885lbb.110 - gsmtp


----- Original message -----

DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
        d=gmail.com; s=20120113;
        h=from:content-type:mime-version:content-transfer-encoding:subject:to
         :date:message-id;
        bh=XIT/LAmN67IRi9HrLcISdd0LCPh/Bo8BtcnOZ3a1r2M=;
        b=jIlBIOhiXVxumR9TmTigQTJL23bh5NiaGHVZr7zOdIbVaQ/o3Ud3F7S7xlYdgrdF7X
         f8kZwMY59Q405rfxv5dmkDm5cAu7XTHJANpbhdMgk0zDySh9ohxJSPDNZ53fMDMubPZN
         Y2HAYFGrB51nyld/wSfBJ/tOgxZ25kA//g/1wLhfCZOiU5zOVlMhl/T38W7bIRXpgSuy
         MwPWeUWJ7HfLOaCbuXNcizVvUxzieq5aKrIw5I16TmNfkp40oCR3oBnBR1hx8gvPim4x
         6IR+GhAwo5Zj9XNmFhnIp/EjxU4DV9OsgUelAqfyPRQ80M4RWE/qaWXqxJs2HGJ6+2gI
         bc/w==
X-Received: by 10.112.61.136 with SMTP id p8mr23610717lbr.107.1429696044965;
        Wed, 22 Apr 2015 02:47:24 -0700 (PDT
```

)

I think it might have to do with that the resetting views are bound to the Django admin views so I've tried with changing the registration - templates by extending it with my own base.html as is done in this blog http://garmoncheg.blogspot.se/2012/07/django-resetting-passwords-with.html but it doesn't work with. I've also added the following change_password function in views.

in urls.py

```
   url(r'^password/change/$',
                     auth_views.password_change,
                     {'post_change_redirect': reverse_lazy('auth_password_change_done')},
                     name='my_password_change'),
    url(r'^password/change/done/$',
                     auth_views.password_change_done,
                     name='password_change_done'),
    url(r'^password/reset/$',
                     auth_views.password_reset,
                     {'post_reset_redirect': reverse_lazy('auth_password_reset_done')},
                     name='password_reset'),
    url(r'^password/reset/done/$',
                     auth_views.password_reset_done,
                     name='password_reset_done'),
    url(r'^password/reset/complete/$',
                     auth_views.password_reset_complete,
                     name='password_reset_complete'),
    url(r'^password/reset/confirm/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>.+)/$',
                     auth_views.password_reset_confirm,
                     {'post_reset_redirect': reverse_lazy('auth_password_reset_complete')},
                     name='password_reset_confirm'),

      #and now add the registration urls
   url(r'', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
```

in views

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import password_change

def my_password_change(request):
        return password_change(template_name='password_change_form.html', extra_context={'my_var1': my_var1})


def password_change(request,
                    template_name='registration/password_change_form.html',
                    post_change_redirect=None,
                    password_change_form=PasswordChangeForm,
                    current_app=None, extra_context=None):
    if post_change_redirect is None:
        post_change_redirect = reverse('django.contrib.auth.views.password_change_done')
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = password_change_form(user=request.user, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(post_change_redirect)
    else:
        form = password_change_form(user=request.user)
    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    if extra_context is not None:
        context.update(extra_context)
    return TemplateResponse(request, template_name, context,
                            current_app=current_app)
```

Comment: Can you send other emails? Can you simplify the code to the bare bones - easier to trouble shoot.

Comment: It worked in the terminal when testing it. The code is from Django's docs

Answer (score 1):

Here unfortunately I don't see any mail sending code(i.e. `send_mail(...)`) in the view function you have written, which should be probably in `password_reset` or in `password_reset_form`. You need to add that to send email(for example) like this:

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail

send_mail('subject', 'email_body', 'from_email_address@gmail.com' , ['to_email_address@gmail.com'], fail_silently=False)
```

Comment: it works for sending and gmail receives the mail but won't accept it, I've updated info with the errormessage that I'm getting. Could it have to do with the Django admin reset views still being used? I've tried to ovverride the Django admin reset views but it doesn't change to my base.html

Comment: you need to add a valid mail address to receive email, that is why you are getting that error. And for implementation, django admin reset view is used like here: https://github.com/django/django/blob/89559bcfb096ccc625e0e9ab41e2136fcb32a514/django/contrib/auth/views.py, and overriding is easy. Here is how I have implemented http://ruddra.com/blog/2014/10/21/make-own-forgot-slash-reset-password-in-django/ and source: https://github.com/skyrudy/django-reset-password/tree/master @user1749431

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried logging in to the Gmail account after running your code?

You might have to allow your app to send emails using your Gmail.

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

Comment: I've now tried with changing the gmail settings to allowing less secure apps by following the link and got a confirmation email from google about it but I still don't receieve the resetting email sent from my app.

Answer (score 0):

This is my working configuration for sending mail in django via gmail smtp:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'youruser@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'yourpassword'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```